# How to Add buttons or Label on existing Grid programmatically using Xamarin Form?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin Form. My requirement is that. I would like to add the button or like Custom Button  or labels etc dynamically (Code behind) on demand bases on existing `Grid` (as code below) Xamarin.Form.  But I do not know the way to add the items on existing `Grid` like. I have tried a lot to find any sample but no success.

My XAML Code as below..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                      xmlns:Status="clr-namespace:SourceCode.Mobile.UI.StatusDetails"                
                     x:Class="SourceCode.Mobile.UI.ConsumableScreen">
    <ContentPage.Content>

        <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Padding="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" RowSpacing="1" ColumnSpacing="1" BackgroundColor="White">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!--   These below button should be from code behind dynamically -->

            <Button  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Device A" WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Clicked="Button_1_Clicked"></Button>
            <Button  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Device B" WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Clicked="Button_2_Clicked"></Button>
            <Button  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="Device C" WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="White" Clicked="Button_3_Clicked"></Button>
        </Grid>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace SourceCode.Mobile.UI
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ConsumableScreen : ContentPage
    {            

        public ConsumableScreen( )
        {
            InitializeComponent();  
        }   

    }
}
```

Can anybody can help me how to create the `Button` or any other control like `Label`, `TextBox` etc on existing cell of `Grid` from code behind.

Thanks in advance.

Susheel

Comment: There are oddles of examples on the xamarin site, have you looked?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter17

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Text = "Device B";
button.Clicked = Button_2_Clicked;
button.WidthRequest = 150.0;
button.HeightRequest = 50.0;
button.HorizontalOptions = Xamarin.Forms.LayoutOptions.Center;
button.VerticalOptions = Xamarin.Forms.LayoutOptions.Center;
button.Color = Xamarin.Forms.Color.White;
Grid.SetRow(button, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(button, 1);
MainGrid.Children.Add(button);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this code in e.g. constructor of xaml.cs class

```
MainGrid.Children.Add(new Label()
        {
            Text = "My new label"
        },0,0);
```

0, 0 on the end is number of column and row in grid.

MainGrid is name of Grid, which you added in xaml file

More information is in documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter17

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this to add a label to your existing Grid

```
Label label = new Label();
label.Text = $"Hello World";

MainGrid.Children.Add(label);
```